# converting unicode emotion characters while parsing from api result (excel macro)

Tags: vba, excel, unicode, excel-2010

After I have parsed API results in Excel, I have trouble with unicode characters. There are lots of emoticons like smilies and hearts etc.

They appear like `\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude09`, but I want them to display like this:

'this is my code

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
objHTTP.Open "Get", URL, False
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE   6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"

objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

objHTTP.send


''objHTTP.Response.contentType = "text/xml"


strResult = objHTTP.ResponseText

strResult = Replace(strResult, "\u0026", "&", 1)

strResult = Replace(strResult, "\u011f", "ğ", 1)
strResult = Replace(strResult, "\u011e", "Ğ", 1)
```

Comment: @DirkReichel I am pretty much new here. here I added the code lines.

Comment: `ResponseText` directly returns the code. and having `\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude09` in that code to show special characters you also will get exactly that (because nothing will be evaluated). this way you need to manually *"translate"* it and your code looks ok... "replace" every single character :(

Comment: What is the full response from the API? Is it returning JSON?

Comment: Anyway those sequences are easy to decode programatically:  = `U+01F609 — WINKING FACE` → encode as UTF-16: `[0xd83d, 0xde09]` → convert to `\uXXXX` escape sequences: `"\ud83d\ude09"`

Comment: @roeland yes it is returning from jason. i am connecting to instagram api. and response is very long, i cant paste it here.

Comment: For now I simply removed all unicode emoticon characters.

Comment: @Ozgur Hm I don't know if there's an easy way to parse JSON with VBA, it's worth looking around for a library or function to do that.